# Can I create a facebook app automatically(from a java program) using any api from a java program or servlet?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, restfb

I am searching for an automated mechanism to create a facebook app from my java program/servlet.

Usually, I have to go to developers.facebok.com, then click the "Apps" link at the top, then hit the "Create new App" button and create an app by providing the site url etc.

I am having a requirement where a user enters his facebook id in my site and hits the "Create App" button. My site will authenticate with facebook using OAuth 2.0 and will have to create an app in the users account. The app generally points to the user's profile page of my site.

Is it possible to do this? Can any one help me?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no you can't. You have to verify that you are a human when you create an app, and facebook intentionally do not provide a way to programmatically create apps.

Comment: Suppose that we ask the user to already create an app, then come back to our site, enter his App ID and App secret, then my site will login into facebook and change his app's site url and necessary fields. Is this possible?

Comment: No. You can't ask for someone's app secret! The clue is in the name. You also can't programmatically change an app's settings